# salesforce function : Pushing changes to functions... failed

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, salesforce-functions

When I deploy function to connected org using command

`sf deploy functions --connected-rg=rule_engine`

I am getting the following error:

> Pushing changes to functions... failed  TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'message')

Reference Code : https://github.com/trailheadapps/functions-recipes.git

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed with updating the CLI to the latest version. Please check https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/tree/main/releasenotes for the latest  release of the cli.